# Text inside element in desktop and outside in mobile

Tags: html, css

Good day I have been working in a responsive header which has a text inside an element but only in desktop screens, opening on mobile screens text should go after the element but with some formatting styles.

I'm aware "content" property doesn't support html tags so I'm running out of non-janky ideas regarding

http://codepen.io/tillegomezz/pen/rrjJxR

```css
header {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background: lightblue;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  header span {
    display: none;
  }
  .content:before {
    content: "<h1>Title Outside</h1>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <span> Title Inside </span>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum foo bar so on.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rather than putting a link inside a code block to bypass the code requirement, it's advisable to just put the code in the actual body of your question. People on this site would be much more likely to help you that way.

Comment: k, thank you @Serlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use CSS to style your element :

```
.content:before {
  content: "Title Outside";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: ...;
}
```

Comment: How about with a break line?
`content: "Title<br> outside"`

Comment: You can't use html in this case. The solution is to add the HTML tag in the HTML and do what you want with the CSS with hidding the elements

Comment: That's exactly what I did, two divs one for mobile and another for desktop and toggle (hide / show) at break screen media query.

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok. just change in this section-

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
header span {display: none;}

      .content:before {
  content: "Title Outside";
  }
 }
```

```css
header {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
  
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  header span {display: none;}

      .content:before {
  content: "Title Outside";
   
  
 
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <span> Title Inside </span>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum foo bar so on.
  </div>
</div>
```